# Getting this error when I try to create a table on my page - IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

    <!-- ** JavaScript ** -->
    <script src="products.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="purchased.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        clear_table = function( ) {
            var table = document.getElementById( "cart_table" );
            while(table.hasChildNodes( )) {
                table.removeChild( table.firstChild );
            }
        }

        make_table = function( items ) {

            // ** Load items into table and calc total **
            var total = 0;

            var table = document.getElementById("cart_table");
            for(var x = 0; x < items.length; x++){
                var tr = table.insertRow( x + 1 );
                var item = tr.insertCell( 0 );
                var price = tr.insertCell( 1 );
                item.innerHTML = items[x].name;
                price.innerHTML = "$" + items[x].price;

                //remove button
                var remove_btn = document.createElement( "button" );
                remove_btn.className = "btn_remove";
                remove_btn.href = "#";
                remove_btn.index = x;
                var btn_text = document.createTextNode( "x" );
                remove_btn.appendChild( btn_text );

                var remove = tr.insertCell( 2 );
                remove.appendChild( remove_btn );

                remove_btn.onclick = function() {
                    items.delete(this.index);

                    var ids = new Array();
                    for( var x = 0; x < items.length; x++ ){
                        ids.push( items[x].id );
                    }

                    save_purchased( ids );
                    clear_table( );
                    make_table( items );
                    return false;
            }

            //total
            total += ( items[x].price );

        }//end build table loop
            //insert total
            var tr = table.insertRow(x+1);
            var item = tr.insertCell( 0 );
            var price = tr.insertCell( 1 );
            item.innerHTML = "Total: ";
            price.innerHTML = "$" + total;

        }

        window.onload = function() {

            // ** Get orders id form cookie **
            var order = load_purchased();

            // ** Load orders products from cookie id into items[] **
            var items = new Array();
            for( var x = 0; x < order.length; x++ ){
                items.push( get_product( order[x] ) );
                //alert( items[x].name );
            }

            make_table( items );

        }//end window.onload()

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <heading>

        <h1>Cart</h1>

        <a href="home.html"><button class="btn_cart">&larr; Home</button></a>

    </heading>

    <div id="content">

        <table id="cart_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <a href="checkout.html"><button class="btn_cart">Order &rarr;</button></a>

    </div>
</body>
```

What is causing this error? ( `IndexSizeError`: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount )

The error happens when `make_table()` executes from `remove_link.onclick` event.

This `make_table()` function first executes from `window.onload()` and it creates my table. It executes fine with no errors.

But when I click the remove button next to an item to remove it from the table. `remove_link.onclick()` executes which executes `make_table()` function again to re-create the table without the unwanted item and calc the new total.

Well... The function doesnt work when it executes the 2nd time, and I get this error( `IndexSizeError`: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount )

The console says its on line 27, which is this line ( `var tr = table.insertRow( x + 1 );` ).

However, I can refresh the page and the page will load fine again with the item I removed gone. so its only when the `make_table()` function gets called form `onclick` event.

Comment: What does `save_purchased()` do? I noticed that on page-load, you're pushing the cookie into an `items` array. However, when you delete an item, you're calling the same `get_purchased()` as on page load, but setting the array to it directly. I feel the problem may lie within you're re-fetching of the cookie, but the cookie isn't actually being properly updated when you delete an item.

Comment: if you use insertCell(-1) and insertRow(-1) it will automatically be added as the last row and you don't have to do calculations

Comment: why are you putting a button in an anchor then in the cell? Why not put the button straight in the cell and attach the event handler to that?

Comment: @Bindrid , Your right, thanks! That should clean up the code a little. I usually link my buttons in html, so when I was writing it I had that prototype in mind.

Comment: @Santi , `load_purchased()` & `save_purchased()` are inside `purchased.js`. `load_purchased()` pulls the cookie that has the id's to my products. I delete the item I want out of that array and `save_purchased()` updates the cookie again with the new id's to my products. Then I call `make_table( items )` pass the new items and it should create it, but instead I get this error(IndexSizeError).

Comment: @Santi , I see what you said about that, I think I fixed it ( I edited the code in the question too ), yet I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was happening when the `make_table()` function executed a 2nd time from the `remove_btn.onclick()` to re-make the table so it appears without the removed item.

The 1st time `make_table()` executed, the math worked out fine as I did it relying on my x's value from the for loop. ( you can see these lines below )

```
var tr = table.insertRow( x + 1 );
var item = tr.insertCell( 0 );
var price = tr.insertCell( 1 );
```

The 2nd time `make_table()` executed from `remove_btn.onclick()` , I believe the value of x was off causing the IndexSizeError.

I changed the values like @Bindrid suggested to:

```
var tr = table.insertRow( -1 );
var item = tr.insertCell( -1 );
var price = tr.insertCell( -1 );
```

...and my IndexSizeError went away.

*I also had to remove the hardcoded HTML `<th>` from my table and have my `make_table()` dynamically insert my `<th>` heading sence my `clear_table()` was clearing the `<th>` heading out too along with my table and my JS was not dynamically re-creating the `<th>`*

Thanks for the help, **@Bindrid** & **@Santi** !!!

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar case. After reading my code again and again, I see silly error.

```
let Row = LicenseTableBody.insertRow( rowIndex );
let cell0 = Row.insertCell(0);
// let cell1 = Row.insertCell(1);
let cell2 = Row.insertCell(2);
let cell3 = Row.insertCell(3);
```

And it was giving me error mentioned in the title. I figured I was mistakenly trying to insert cell at position `2` immediately after `0`. That's not good sequence.

So, I just changed the sequence to right order like below:

```
let Row = LicenseTableBody.insertRow( rowIndex );
let cell0 = Row.insertCell(0);
// let cell1 = Row.insertCell(1);
let cell2 = Row.insertCell(1);
let cell3 = Row.insertCell(2);.
```

Off course, I was a silly error.

Hope this helps,